# Web API OAuthAuthorizationServer using Authorization Code flow

Tags: asp.net, oauth, asp.net-web-api, owin, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on `Asp.net MVC5 app` and a `Web APi2` ,The API is to be used across multiple sites and to be used to authenticate the user as well.

I have created the MVC5 and Web API project in `VS 2013`,The default template for the authorization server comes whith `grant_type=password`,but I am looking for implemantation using Code authorization flow.

I have created the Login view in my WebAPI+MVC project which should be called by the client application
I should validate the user using username and password 
If user is valid then pass the Authorize code to the client application using redirect Uri

I am getting confused in integrating above flow using owin "**OAuthAuthorizationServer**" 
or what exactly I should override in below method

```
public override Task GrantAuthorizationCode(OAuthGrantAuthorizationCodeContext context)
{
    return base.GrantAuthorizationCode(context);
}
```

I will be thankful if any one can guide me with the implementation.

Comment: Have you solved the puzzle.